# Google GEOchart, How to remove map key

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using [Google Geochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart), I have the same color in the map, so I don't need the map key -I don't know his name- in the bottom.
How I can remove or hide it
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following option...

`legend: 'none'`